# Что за тип size_t?

Tags: c++

Что представляет из себя тип **size_t**, похожий на тип **int**? И для чего его используют?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Открываем [cplusplus.com - size_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/size_t/) и читаем

> size_t
> Unsigned integral type

беззнаковое целое. То есть, это не int, он знаковый.

> Alias of one of the fundamental unsigned integer types.

Псевдоним для одного из фундаментальных без знаковых типов. (то есть, скорее всего 4 или 8 байтового).

> It is a type able to represent the size of any object in bytes: size_t is the type returned by the sizeof operator and is widely used in the standard library to represent sizes and counts.

Предназначен для отображения **размера** любого объекта в байтах: это возвращает size_of и много функций стандартной библиотеки - всякие length и count.

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно.

Comment: Если коротко, то целое без знака 32 бит на 32-разрядных и 64 бит на 64-разрядных CPU (размер `size_t` должен совпадать с размером указателя для данной платформы).

Comment: @avp, Почему размер указателя должен совпадать с размером `size_t`?

Comment: Потому что указатель должен быть в состоянии адресовать **любой** байт в памяти, а `size_t` хранить размер **любого** (в т.ч. занимающего **всю память**) объекта.

Comment: @avp, А где сказано, что реализация обязательно должна позволять создавать объекты занимающие всю память? Что мешает реализации ограничить размер любого объекта в байтах величиной 65535, но при этом использовать 64-битные указатели?

Comment: @wololo, вы можете делать в своих реализациях как вам нравится и возиться с этим как вам хочется. Я же для себя решаю, что равенство размеров этих типов удобно.

Comment: @avp, Хм, ну да, пожалуй могу. И Вы можете для себя решать что угодно и возиться с этим как Вам хочется, однако, всё же стоит заметить, что стандарт языка не гарантирует, что размер указателя совпадает с размером типа `size_t`.

Answer (score 5):

Тип size_t обычно применяется для счетчиков циклов, индексации массивов, хранения размеров, адресной арифметики. Так как его размер совпадает с размером указателя. Если для этих целей использовать (unsigned int ) то на 64х разрядной платформе могут быть проблемы с корректной работой приложения, а также теоретическое(на уровне одной - двух лишних инструкций) снижение производительности при индексации.