# Тип size_t в c++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, типы-данных, c++14

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает size_t? То есть, я читал, что в 64-битной системе, size_t занимает 64 бита. Но ведь, если у нас есть массив, например, из 20 целых чисел `int arr[20] = {1, 2, ..., 20}`, то в таком массиве - 80 байт, потому что каждое целое число занимает 4 байта. И по сути, когда мы пишем: `size_t arrsize = sizeof(arr)`, то выходит, что arrsize занимает 80 байт, и тогда по идее нельзя применять size_t, поскольку size_t занимает 64 бита в 64-битной системе. В чем ошибка?

P.S. И в чем тогда вообще смысл от size_t, если и long long тоже занимает 8 байт в 64-битной системе? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *"arrsize занимает 80 байт"* Он не "занимает" 80 байт. В нем будет записано **число** 80, которое вполне умещается в 64 бита (т.к. меньше 2^64). *"в чем тогда вообще смысл от size_t, если и long long тоже занимает 8 байт"* А что на счет 32-битных систем?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387641/Что-за-тип-size-t возможно здесь ответы на ваши вопросы