# Цикличная сортировка на C

Tags: c, сортировка

Я хочу понять циклическую сортировку. Приведенный ниже код не мой.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int cycleSort(int * list, size_t l_len);
void show_array(int * array, size_t a_len);
 
/*
 * Sort an array in place and return the number of writes.
 */
int cycleSort(int * list, size_t l_len)
{
  int writes = 0;
 
  /* Loop through the array to find cycles to rotate. */
  for (int cycleStart = 0; cycleStart < l_len - 1; ++cycleStart)
  {
    int item = list[cycleStart];
    int swap_tmp;
 
    /* Find where to put the item. */
    int pos = cycleStart;
    for (int i = cycleStart + 1; i < l_len; ++i)
    {
      if (list[i] < item)
      {
        ++pos;
      }
    }
 
    /* If the item is already there, this is not a cycle. */
    if (pos == cycleStart)
    {
      continue;
    }
 
    /* Otherwise, put the item there or right after any duplicates. */
    while (item == list[pos])
    {
      ++pos;
    }
    swap_tmp = list[pos];
    list[pos] = item;
    item = swap_tmp;
    ++writes;
 
    /* Rotate the rest of the cycle. */
    while (pos != cycleStart)
    {
      /* Find where to put the item. */
      pos = cycleStart;
      for (int i = cycleStart + 1; i < l_len; ++i)
      {
        if (list[i] < item)
        {
          ++pos;
        }
      }
 
      /* Put the item there or right after any duplicates. */
      while (item == list[pos])
      {
        ++pos;
      }
      swap_tmp = list[pos];
      list[pos] = item;
      item = swap_tmp;
      ++writes;
    }
  }
 
  return writes;
}
 
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 9, 3, 5, 5, 8, 4, 7, 0, 6, };
  int arr_k = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  int writes;
 
  show_array(arr, arr_k);
  writes = cycleSort(arr, arr_k);
  show_array(arr, arr_k);
  printf("writes: %d\n", writes);
 
  return 0;
}
 
void show_array(int * array, size_t a_len)
{
  for (int ix = 0; ix < a_len; ++ix)
  {
    printf("%d ", array[ix]);
  }
  putchar('\n');
 
  return;
}
```

2. При инициализации функции `cycleSort()` указывается `int *list, size_t l_len`. Правильно ли я понимаю,
   что `int *list` - это указатель на целочисленный массив? Правильно ли я понимаю, что `size_tl_len` - это размер массива? Если да, то как еще можно представить `size_t`, например, `int SIZE`?
3. Строка `int main(int argc, char **argv) {`. Почему мы вообще объявили `int argc, char **argv`? Я спрашиваю, потому что я не видел переменную `argc` в теле `main()` и абсолютно не понимал, что такое `**argv`. Является ли это двойным указателем на массив? Тогда возникает вопрос, чем его можно заменить, например, `*mass`? Или ** означает указатель на динамический массив? Нужно ли использовать имена `argc` и `**argv`, например, мне нравятся просто `variable` и `**pointer_dynamic_mass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Верно, `int *list` — это указатель на массив целочисленных данных, равно как и `size_t l_len` — размер массива. Что же касается других вариантов, то можно использовать и `int` в качестве типа — если точно уверены, что передастся именно **неотрицательное число**. `size_t`, как можно выяснить из ответов к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387641/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-size-t) вопросу, есть псевдоним для одного из беззнаковых типов (32 или 64-битного целого типа), предназначенный для отображения размера любого объекта в байтах.
2. Мы можем и не объявлять параметры `int argc, char** argv`, т.е. это необязательные аргументы, предназначенные для количества аргументов командной строки и массива всех строк этой же командной строки соответственно. Более подробную информацию Вы можете прочесть, например, [здесь](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/bcb/argcargv.php).

Comment: Благодарю. Эмпирическим путем до получения вашего ответа на 2 вопрос дошел!